Subquery in mongodb using not in
I have some problems getting a query with the following:
I want to select the records whose date is less than or equal to a date given by parameters but I also have to take into account that the records can be grouped by a group. If in the first selection by date, there is a record from the same group, this selection cannot be performed.
If it were MySQL, I could first select the ids that meet a date less than fechaParam and a NOT IN with a subquery of records with a date greater than fechaParam.
How to do this in mongo?
This is the example collection:


{
    _id:0,
    date: "2024-07-18T05:43:21.000Z",
    group:"1",
    state:"DONE"
    
},
{
    _id:1,
    date: "2024-07-18T06:43:21.000Z",
    group:"2",
    state:"DONE"
    
},
{
    _id:2,
    date: "2024-07-18T07:43:21.000Z",
    group:"1",
    state:"FAILED"
    
},
{
    _id:3,
    date: "2024-07-18T08:43:21.000Z",
    group:"1",
    state:"DONE"
    
},
{
    _id:4,
    date: "2024-07-18T09:43:21.000Z",
    group:"2",
    state:"FAILED"
    
}




I think in SQL it could be this query:
select * from messages where date <= "2024-07-18T09:43:21.000Z"
and id not in ( select id from messages where date > "2024-07-18T09:43:21.000Z")

test
aggregate([
{
$match: {
date: { $lte: ISODate("2024-07-18T09:43:21.000Z") }
}
},
{
$lookup: {
from: "messages",
let: { id: "$_id" },
pipeline: [
{
$match: {
$expr: {
$and: [
{ $gt: ["$date", ISODate("2024-07-18T09:43:21.000Z")] },
{ $eq: ["$_id", "$$id"] }
]
}
}
}
],
as: "filteredMessages"
}
},
{
$match: {
"filteredMessages": { $eq: [] }
}
}
])

Please post your question in English as this StackOverflow is only allowed using English. If you have translate it, then remove the non-English part. Thanks.

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Would you please attach the expected output and the explanation around it? For now, your attempt and raw SQL seems functionally equivalent to this
